# Toggle active class in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

How can I toggle a class in ng-repeat when onclick each item.My code does not work.Thank you,

This is my code.

```
 <a class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="connect in Connected" ng-click="getChat(connect.TokenId, connect.SessionId); getOnline(connect.SupportId, connect.TokenId, connect.SessionId, connect.CreateTime); onClickTab(connect.TokenId)" ng-class="{'active': $index == selectedIndex}" ng-init="$first && getChat(connect.TokenId, connect.SessionId); $first && getOnline(connect.SupportId, connect.TokenId, connect.SessionId, connect.CreateTime)">
              <h4 class="list-group-item-heading"><strong ng-bind="connect.SupportId"></strong></h4>
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                  <li><strong>Token ID :<strong ng-bind="connect.TokenId"></strong> </li>
                  <li>
                    <strong>Online :</strong> 
                    <span class="Connect" ng-if="connect.SessionId != undefined" class="ConnectIcon"><div class="ConnectIcon"></div></span>
                  </li>
                  <li><span>Chat Duration: </span> <strong ng-bind="connect.CreateTime | DateGap"></strong></li>
                </ul>
            </a>
```

in my controller:

```
 $scope.onClickTab= function(x){
      $scope.selectedIndex= x;
    };
```

Comment: just use `ng-class="{'active': $index == connect.TokenId}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
onClickTab($index)
```

not the id.